# Matching of Correlograms of two image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find the similarity between two images using Correlogram. I have already created Correlograms (2D) for both the images.

**Task:** Now i want to find out how similar these two Correlograms are.

**Problem:** I do not how can i match these two Correlograms. Can i match them in the similar way in which we match [**two histograms**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html#theory)?

**Formula comparision:**
As per a research paper, the mathematical formulas of histogram matching and Correlogram matching are following. It can be seen clearly that in case of histogram, the summation is taken only for the difference between the corresponding values of color bins. Whereas, in case of Correlogram matching, the summation is taken over two dimensions i.e. distance, color bins.

[image]

**My code:**  i have two images i.e. `Mat correlogram1` and `Mat correlogram2` in which i am storing the values of Correlogram for two images. Then, i am trying to match them using the following code which is based upon the formula mentioned above.

```
double correlogramMatching(Mat correlogram1, Mat correlogram2)
{
    double confidenceValue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ColorBins; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<DistanceRange; j++)
        {       
            double value = (std::abs) ( (correlogram1.at<double>(i,j) - correlogram2.at<double>(i,j))  /  (1 + correlogram1.at<double>(i,j) + correlogram1.at<double>(i,j)) );
            confidenceValue = confidenceValue + value;
        }
    }
    return confidenceValue;
}
```

**Confusion:** For the two same images, the value of confidanceValue is **Zero** and for two not so common images the values are like 66, 88....so on. So, upto which values should i predict if the two images are similar or not?

**PS:** I am doing the programming in OpenCV (C++).

Comment: Never heard about correlogram. What's the difference with a histogram?

Comment: @memecs: Histogram just keep the global information about colors. I mean that histogram will tell you about what is the probability of a particular color in that image. Whereas, correlogram is an extension and is a very powerful technique. It keeps information about both the color and their spatial distribution.

Comment: I would say that if you create a Correlogram using Zero mean normalized correlation, then you can compare them without a problem. Well, thats why zero mean normalized correlation is used anyways.

Comment: @skm - I wrote an answer.  Correlograms / Co-occurrence matrices are something that I know very well as I used it as the backbone for an image retrieval framework I worked on several years ago.  Good luck!

Comment: @skm - Basically you are determining what threshold is considered to be similar or dissimilar.  Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for that. It all depends on your application, what images you have, as well as you manually testing various thresholds out yourself.  As such.... it's all a matter of testing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A correlogram is also a co-occurrence matrix / histogram.  To answer your question, the simple answer is yes.  Remember, when you're comparing histograms by themselves, you are comparing the grayscale / colour content between two images / patches.  By extending this to correlograms / co-occurrence matrices, you are also comparing **the spatial distributions of the colours** as well, which are handled by the third dimension, the distance, of the histogram.  If you had two images that had the same colour distribution, but the spatial distributions are different, the histogram measures will also take this into account and will report a high dissimilarity / low similarity between them.

As such, you are perfectly fine in using standard histogram comparison measures between two correlograms (and I'm also speaking from experience).  As such, you can simply use any standard techniques that compare histograms together.  Examples include histogram intersection, the `L_p` norm, the chi-squared distance, the Bhattacharyya distance and so on.

Take a look at the following link for more details.  There are some great histogram similarity / dissimilarity measures you can use to compare between two histograms, each with their own advantages and disadvantages.  Also, Ander Biguri raised a good point.  Be sure to normalize the contrast between each view to make the content between the histograms somewhat contrast and illumination independent.

Link: http://pi-virtualworld.blogspot.ca/2013/09/histogram-similarity.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question, kindly have a look on it. As per the formulas (mentioned in my question), we have to do the summation over both the dimensions i.e. color bins and distance. Please have a look at my short code and please tell me if i have done it correct? Also, i am not sure upto which values we can say that the two images are similar because more dissimilar the images are, more will be the value of cofidenceValue.